# can't copy folder into docker container

Tags: docker, go, containers

I have a local folder called `images` that contains bunch of folders and files within. When I run the container I get the following error:
the command I execute: `docker run -t -i file-uploader -token=abcdefgh`

```
panic: failed Walk: Failed to walk directory: *fs.PathError lstat ./images/: no such file or directory

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /src/main.go:57 +0x357
```

Here is the `Dockerfile` I created:

```
FROM golang:1.16
WORKDIR /src
COPY go.sum go.mod ./
RUN go mod download
COPY ./images/ images/
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o /bin/app .
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/app"]

FROM scratch
COPY --from=0 /bin/app /bin/app
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/app"]
```

And, here is the code in the program:

```
var (
    token = flag.String("token", "", "user's token for application")
    rootpath = flag.String("rootpath", "./images/","folder path to be uploaded")
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    if *token == "" {
        log.Fatal(Red + "please provide a client token => -token={$token}")
    }

    tokenSource := oauth2.StaticTokenSource(&oauth2.Token{AccessToken: *token})
    oauthClient := oauth2.NewClient(context.TODO(), tokenSource)
    client := putio.NewClient(oauthClient)

    paths := make(chan string)
    var wg = new(sync.WaitGroup)
    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(paths, wg, client)
    }
    if err := filepath.Walk(*rootpath, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("Failed to walk directory: %T %w", err, err)
        }
        if !info.IsDir() {
            paths <- path
        }
        return nil
    }); err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("failed Walk: %w", err))
    }
    close(paths)
    wg.Wait()
}
}
```

If flag is not provided, its default value is the folder itself which is `./images/`. When I run this normally like: `go run main.go -token="abcde"`, it works properly. I did some changes on `Dockerfile`. Some of the changes I made and tried again and again.:

- replacing `COPY . .` with `COPY ./images/ /images`. It should automatically creates a folder inside `/src` like `/src/images` and get the local folder from host and put into it. It didn't work.
- I also did try `COPY . .`, believing that it will copy everything from host into docker container. It didn't work either.
- I did put 2 `COPY` command together. Didn't work.
- `COPY . ./` didn't work either.

My structure of the project is as follows:

```
/file-uploader-cli
     /images
     Dockerfile
     file-uploader-cli (binary)
     go.mod with go.sum
     main.go
```

How can I put `/images` folder into container and run it properly?
Extra question: `/images` folder is approx. 500 MB or something. Is it a good practice to put that folder into a container?

I guess it is possible to copy a folder like `docker cp {$folder_name} ${container_id}:/{$path}`, but it must be a running container or something? I did try this using `image_id` replacing the `container_id` but I got an error like `No such container:path: 12312312312:/`.

`EDIT:`
the problem is the `scratch` image which was done in order to reduce the size. However, when I delete the `scratch` thing, the size of the image became 1.1 GB. Any easier or convenient way to utilize the `images` folder without having too much size?

Comment: i think the problem is that in the final image, you only have `/bin/app` but no `images` directory. can you try copying `images` into `/bin/`?

Comment: It didn't work either.

Comment: I guess, since `scratch` does not contain anything, basically it's empty, that is why I can't access to `images` folder. Will try something different.

Comment: If your goal is to process the `image` directory on your host system, it will probably be easier to directly run the Go application there; introducing an isolation system like Docker makes things harder and doesn't match your needs.

Comment: try with a different base image instead of `scratch`. like `debian:buster` for example.

Comment: It's because of the `scratch` image. That was the problem. However, the image size is now 1.1 GB with the `images` folder. So, you're saying don't dockerize the app? Is there any efficient or easier way to do this? reaching the host document from the container or smh?

Comment: @jakub with `debian:buster` it becomes 121 MB. thanks. Any approaches to reduce the size of the image to less than 121 MB?

Comment: @baris - does it work with `debian:buster`? you can try `debian:buster-slim`. you can also try with `alpine`, but if you do, you will have to use a golang alpine image (maybe `golang:1.16-alpine`

Comment: I'm a big fan of Docker, but I don't usually containerize Go programs because they have few runtime dependencies on the userspace.  Still, its perfectly valid to put a Go program in a container.  The `scratch` container will also require CA certificates if you're to make TLS connections eg HTTPS

Comment: @jakub yes. it worked with `debian:buster`. I'll try the other ones you mentioned. thanks

Comment: @baris - please see my answer. i demonstrate how to build this docker image using an alpine base

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `images` when building your app, you need it when executing your app.  Instead of adding `images` to the first image, add it to the final image:

```
FROM golang:1.16 AS builder
WORKDIR /src
COPY go.sum go.mod ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o /bin/app .

FROM scratch
WORKDIR /
copy images .
COPY --from=builder /bin/app /bin/app
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/app"]
```

Or, if you want to provide images dynamically, you could mount it at runtime.

I also recommend removing docker containers automatically unless you actually want them sticking around.  Otherwise you end up with lots and lots of `Exited` containers.

```
docker run --rm -it -v /my/path/to/images:/images:ro file-uploader -token=abcdefgh
```

I would also recommend you put your token in an environment variable so its not saved in bash history and docker runtime information.

> So, you're saying don't dockerize the app?

I don't usually containerize Go programs unless containers are a good fit for deployment and operations (eg kubernetes).  Most languages like C/C++, Java, Erlang, Python, Javascript, all require significant runtime components provided by the filesystem - compiled ones are usually  dynamically linked with shared libraries from the operating system, VM based  languages like Java or Erlang require the VM to be installed and configured (and it will likely also have runtime dependencies), and interpreted languages like Python, Ruby, or Javascript require the entire interpreter runtime, as well as any shared libraries the language's libraries are linked to.

Go is an exception to this though.  Ignoring CGo (which I recommend avoiding whenever possible), Go binaries are statically linked and have minimal userspace runtime requirements.  This is why a Go binary is one of the few things that can acutally *work* in a container built `FROM scratch`.   The one exception to this, is that the Go program *will* need CA Certificates from the operating system to validate the certificates on HTTPS servers and other protocols secured with TLS.

I recommend that you don't dockerize the app unless docker is helping you distribute or operate it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the second build stage does not include the `images` directory. I don't think you can use the `scratch` base for this purpose, so we will have to change that. If you are concerned about image size, you should look into into alpine linux. I have converted your Dockerfile to use alpine.

```
FROM golang:1.16-alpine
WORKDIR /src
COPY go.sum go.mod ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o /bin/app .
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/app"]

FROM alpine:3.15.0
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY --from=0 /bin/app app
COPY images .
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/app/app"]
```

Note that I changed the app path in the second build stage to `/opt/app`. I did this because it would be odd to have an image folder under `/bin`. And `/opt` is a common place to store user applications.

As for whether or not you should containerize your code, that is up to you. One of Go's advantages is static compilation and easy cross-compiling. So you could distribute your binary (and images) as is.